# How to push new field in array mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Imagine I have database like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("594994d1ab6c161168aa5969"),
    "user_id" : ObjectId("594994d1ab6c161168aa5968"),
    "active" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "active"
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "inactive"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want add to first object in active array . Here is result I expected

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("594994d1ab6c161168aa5969"),
    "user_id" : ObjectId("594994d1ab6c161168aa5968"),
    "active" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "active",
            "note": [{
                            content: 'here is content',
                            title : ' here is title'
                        }]
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "inactive"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is code I tried

```
db.collection('..').update({'user_id' : ObjectId(userId)} ,
{$push:{ "active.0": "note": [{
                              content: 'here is content',
                                title : ' here is title'
                        }]  } )
```

But I get `The field 'active.0' must be an array but is of type object in document` . Where is my wrong ? Please help

Comment: Should be `{$push:{  "active.0.note": { content: 'here is content', title : ' here is title' } } }`

Comment: @NeilLunn I tried this and it create new field active[0] in db

Comment: @NeilLunn I want add it to first object of array active

Comment: Nope **that** did not. Your previous statement did. You need to remove that from the document and reset to what you had before.

Comment: @NeilLunn What you mean is I should remove active array ?

Comment: You should use active.0.note and $set not $push

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with your document like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("594994d1ab6c161168aa5969"),
    "user_id" : ObjectId("594994d1ab6c161168aa5968"),
    "active" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "active"
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "inactive"
        }
    ]
}
```

You run the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) like this:

```
db.collection.update(
  { "_id" : ObjectId("594994d1ab6c161168aa5969") },
  { "$push":{ "active.0.note": { content: 'here is content', title : ' here is title' } } }
)
```

Which creates the new array within the first element like so:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("594994d1ab6c161168aa5969"),
        "user_id" : ObjectId("594994d1ab6c161168aa5968"),
        "active" : [
                {
                        "type" : "active",
                        "note" : [
                                {
                                        "content" : "here is content",
                                        "title" : " here is title"
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "type" : "inactive"
                }
        ]
}
```

Everything here is cut and paste from my shell.